# How do I verify the sender balance is not more than sending amount (Stellar Compliance)

Tags: federation, bridge-server, compliance, stellar.toml

I am using the Stellar federation protocol and successfully integrated 'stellar bridge', 'stellar federation' and 'stellar compliance'.

1. How do I verify the sender is not sending more than his available account balance?
2. Also what is the use of the `/compliance/ask_user` callback function? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to do anything for #1, do you? Stellar will fail the transaction if the sender does not have enough.